Is it OK to have the back of a service panel flush against a finished wall?
I am installing a subpanel in my basement.  If I place it where it meets other NEC requirements, and the front will be flush with the finished wall, the back of the panel will almost be as deep as the stud cavity, placing the back of the panel against the sheetrock in the hallway.
Is this acceptable?  Is there a risk a future homeowner may drive a nail into the panel?

there is a risk that their nail could find (and open)  a knock-out or even a find a hanging keyhole, but I'm not aware of any requirement to add extra armor to the back of a panel.

on the other hand NFPA doesn't really care about electrocution and a stray nail going into a panel is unlikely to start a fire that spreads to the structure of the building..

Yes, that should be fine. The typical panel is designed to fit just inside a stud bay - i.e., ~ 14.5" wide (studs are 16" on center, subtract 1 2x4 = 1.5" and you get 14.5") and ~ 4" deep (2x4 = 3.5" + 0.5" for drywall).
As far as the metal case, it is comparable to the back of a metal junction box. Which is one more reason to use metal instead of plastic boxes.
While main panels tend to be on an outer wall, there are enough exceptions plus subpanels routinely placed in interior walls, that this is perfectly normal.

This is normal for panels in interior walls
Just about all panels that are flush mounted into an interior stud wall that isn't built to carry drain piping will wind up in the situation you describe.  Panel cabinets are made of thick enough metal that you won't just nail into them by accident (as thick or thicker than a nail plate), anyway.
